# CSS applied to wrong object Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular8

I am receiving 15 objects inside an array. I splice the first 6 and discard remaining. Now in HTML I have 2 carousel pages where I am creating comparison cards for each object. Carousel is of 2 pages with 3 cards (objects) on each page. I want to apply different css style to the first card of the first page only and rest all would be same. But css is getting applied to first card of both the pages. In typescript the logic is as follows:

```
  this.sixIdeasArray = response; // response is received from API call
   for (let i = 0; i < this.sixIdeasArray.length; i ++ ){
     if (i <3) {
       this.threeOrLess.push(this.sixIdeasArray[i]);
     } else if ((i >= 3 && (i < 6){
       this.uptoSix.push(this.sixIdeasArray[i]);
    }
  }
```

Basically I am storing received response in `sixIdeasArray` and then check if the length is less than 3 I am storing it in separate array `threeOrLess`, if it is between 3 and 6 I am storing the first three in `threeOrLess` and next three in `uptoSix`. Then I am assigning these arrays to
`ideasArray`.
Now I have indicators at the bottom of carousel to change the pages. The logic here is to assign `threeOrLess` to `ideasArray` on first page and on change event to next page show `uptoSix`

```
   changePage(){
     this.ideasArray = this.threeOrLess;
   }

   changePage2(){
     this.ideasArray = this.uptoSix;
   }
```

Now in HTML I have for loop on `ideasArray` but it treats first three plans as one array and next three as separate thus applying the CSS class to first object on each page

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let idea of ideasArray; let i = index">
   <ul class="data">
     <li *ngIf = "i == 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
    <li *ngIf = "i != 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now it should treat rest five as `Recommended Idea` and should not apply same style to 1st idea on both pages. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use any boolean variable to track(eg- isRecommandedIdea).Check below code :-

In someComponent.ts

```
isRecommandedIdea: Boolean = false;

changePage(){
this.ideasArray = this.threeOrLess;
isRecommandedIdea = true;
}

changePage2(){
this.ideasArray = this.uptoSix;
isRecommandedIdea = false;
}
```

In someComponent.html

```
    <li *ngIf = "(i == 0)&&isRecommandedIdea" class="header"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
        <li *ngIf = "i != 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
```

You might have to tweak above html code as per to your need.